# revolution slider meta on image gallery

Tags: meta, revolution-slider

I use revolution slider on a series of sites and right now I'm developing  a site that is image based. The images are inside categories and I need to create an image slider in which I can show the title and description of the image with writing that for each image but rathe using the meta of the plugin. I've tried using the meta provided for posts based slider but that doesn't work. Any hep? Thanks

Comment: Please add some examples and make your question more specific

Comment: when creating a post based slider you can use meta like: %title%, %content%, etc that are pulled from the post information. I would like to use the title and description on images the way that is used on post based slides.